# Why spark stream to stream join return empty result?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

When I try to join 2 streams using pyspark streaming, I get an empty result.

I have the following parquet dataset stored in an S3 Bucket.

```
Table A:
ID_a,Ref_a,ts_a
1,X,2021-12-06 04:59:54.075 UTC
...
2,Y,2021-12-06 04:59:54.010 UTC


Table B:
ID_b,Ref_b,ts_b
1,X,2022-05-17 14:26:16.173 UTC
...
3,Z,2022-05-17 14:26:16.176 UTC
```

I sorted the elements of both the tables by ts column, as you can notice, the time difference between each record of the same table, is just about few milliseconds, few times some record have also the same exact timestamp.

There is ~6 months difference in ts between the records of Table A and Table B.

I am trying to join those data as streams:

```
df_a = spark.readStream.schema(...).parquet("s3:...").withWatermark('ts', '1 minute')
df_b = spark.readStream.schema(...).parquet("s3:...").withWatermark('ts', '1 minute')

cond = expr("""
ID_a = ID_b AND
Ref_a = Ref_b AND
ts_a >= ts_b AND
ts_a <= ts_b
""")

a_joined_b = df_a.join(df_b, cond, 'outer')

def print_fn(batch_df, batch_id):
    batch_df.show(n=200, truncate=False)

stream_a_joined_b = a_joined_b.writeStream.trigger(processingTime='60 seconds').foreachBatch(print_fn).start()
```

From the logs I can see that I am getting empty dataframe, for some reason spark is discarding the results.

Comment: `ts_a >= ts_b AND ts_a <= ts_b` this looks suspicious.  It only allows an exact match.

Comment: @Emma I tried to update the condition with: `cond = expr("""ID_a = ID_b AND Ref_a = Ref_b AND ts_b >= ts_a  AND ts_b  <= ts_a + interval 1 year """)`

Now I am getting only the records that are inner joining between the two tables (ID 1). I don't understand why I am not getting ID2 and ID3